# What is the path and command of mounted folder when I "connect to server"?

Tags: command-line, server, mount, sftp, sshfs

I am trying mount a remote machine filesystem to my local machine. The remote machine is a computation cluster which has two file systems. I have space on both file systems and I have a link on my home directory to the other NFS (fastspace).

When I mount my home directory on the remote machine locally

```
sshfs remote: ~/mnt/remote
```

I can access the files but not `fastspace`. If I try to do as much as `ls` in the directory I get

```
ls: cannot open directory .: Input/output error
```

Same goes when I try to

```
sshfs remote:fastspace ~/mnt/remote
```

However, if I try to directly mount my space on `fastspace` things seem OK.

When I try to mount the remote file system using gnome connect to server, everything is fine.

So, I need either the command Gnome use to connect to server or to know the path. How can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

Its unclear if you are using NFS or SSHFS they are not the same afaik. 
I few hints: try using full paths instead of wildcards like ~ 
that can be different depending on the user the command is executed with
so use full paths like /home/username/ 
eg. if my username is sub on the machine called fastspace and would like
to mount my remote home directory to a local folder in my home called mnt:

```
cd ~ ; sshfs fastspace:/home/sub mnt/
```

this is for SSHFS, for NFS you need something like

```
mount fastspace:/home/sub /home/sub/mnt
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm trying to access a filesystem on a remote machine via sshfs. The file system itself is mounted on the remote machine via NFS. I hope that clear this up. I tried to use the full path without any luck.

Comment: Here is an example. I am mounting the DoubleThink volume via NFS on blackjack, than I am mounting it on z420 via sshfs from blackjack: sub@z420:~$ `sshfs blackjack:/mnt/DoubleThink /home/sub/DoubleThink/` You might have some restrictions due to nfs permissions if you can list it on one machine and not on the other and you are using different users

Comment: When I used arch I didn't have such problems. Perhaps the computation server administrator has changed permissions at about the same time.